# Hibernate in JSF Social Application runs out of connections

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm currently writing a JSF based Social Application. I'm also using Hibernate to persist, update and merge data. But at some point my application stops responding with following error.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor848.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1114)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2502)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2320)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor822.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
... 127 more
```

the java code that executes transactions is here:

```
public class TransactionManager {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

public TransactionManager() {

}

public IEntity validateUser(String userName, String userPassword) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String hql = "FROM AccountEntity";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<IAccountEntity> results = query.list();
    for (IAccountEntity user : results) {
        if (user.getUserName().equals(userName) && user.getPassword().equals(userPassword)) {
            session.close();
            sessionFactory.close();
            return user;
        }
    }
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
    return null;
}

public IEntity retrieveUserByName(String userName) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String hql = "FROM AccountEntity A WHERE A.userName = '" + userName + "'";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<IAccountEntity> results = query.list();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
    if (!results.isEmpty()) {
        return results.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}

public IEntity retrievePageByName(String pageName) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String hql = "FROM PageEntity A WHERE A.pageName = '" + pageName + "'";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<IAccountEntity> results = query.list();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
    if (!results.isEmpty()) {
        return results.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}

public Map<IEntity, Integer> save(Object... objects) {
    Map<IEntity, Integer> savedMap = new HashMap<IEntity, Integer>();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    for (Object object : objects) {
        session.save(object);
        savedMap.put((IEntity) object, ((IEntity) object).getId());
    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
    return savedMap;
}

public void merge(IEntity entity) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.update(entity);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
}

// SELECT * FROM `commententity` WHERE id BETWEEN 3 and 5 and
// accountEntityId = 1 ORDER BY id DESC
// SELECT * FROM `commententity` WHERE targetAccountEntity_id='1' ORDER BY
// id LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
// FROM dao.CommentEntity D WHERE targetAccountEntity_id='1' ORDER BY D.id
// DESC
public List<IEntity> retrievePaginatedById(String classType, String targetId, String status, int id, int offset,
        int limit, boolean forContactRequestNotification) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String hql = null;
    if (forContactRequestNotification) {
        hql = "FROM " + classType + " D WHERE " + targetId + "=" + "'" + id + "' AND D.status = '" + status
                + "' ORDER BY D.id DESC";
    } else {
        hql = "FROM " + classType + " D WHERE " + targetId + "=" + "'" + id + "'" + " ORDER BY D.id DESC";
    }
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql).setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(limit);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<IEntity> results = query.list();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
    return results;
}

public List<IEntity> retrieveMultipleById(String classType, String targetId, String status, int id,
        boolean forContactRequestNotification) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String hql = null;
    if (forContactRequestNotification) {
        // SONDERFALL
        hql = "FROM " + classType + " D WHERE D.status = '" + status + "' and " + targetId + "= " + id;
    } else {
        hql = "FROM " + classType + " D WHERE " + targetId + "= " + id;
    }
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<IEntity> results = query.list();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
    return results;
}

public IEntity retrieveById(Class<?> c, int id) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    IEntity entity = (IEntity) session.get(c, id);
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
    return entity;
}

public void delete(IEntity obj) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(obj);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
}

public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

and this is a sample image of how a profile looks like,  I'm supporting lazy loading to avoid big transactions. [image]

I just dont get what am I doing so wrong here. I read somewhere I have to close every connection. But that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: are you using mysql?

Comment: yes I do. I'm using JPA java persistence api to persist, retrieve or update data.

Comment: Well take a look at the code that you posted. If an exception happens in any of your methods, will session.close() get called then? Nope. That's already a possible resource leak.

Comment: I'm aware of a possible leak. I have to investigate more.

Comment: No you are NOT using JPA API. JPA API involves EntityManager not Session, and EntityManagerFactory not SessionFactory. This is Hibernate API.

Answer (score 0):

Please increase the mysql connection size. 
Go to mysql console and run below

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";
```

You will see the maximum allowed connections. You can change them using

```
SET GLOBAL max_connections = 200;
```

Restart mysql server, and it should be working fine.

Comment: Just increasing the size without finding if there is a real resource leak is a bad solution and client and server size max connections should be in balance...

Comment: @Kukeltje that is true, I was just giving an option.

Comment: Yeah @PrasadKharkar if I do that it might give me some more time but not a solution for long sessions.

Comment: Yes @Kukeltje, OP had not pasted the code hence the workaround. This answer can be deleted if OP solves the problem using code itself.